# How to check login date and substract after that add the value to the database?

Tags: sql-server

Is this actually a correct query in terms of syntax:? I need to know if its valid first.

So please let me know.

```
update userdata 
set totaltime = totaltime + (DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE()) - logintime) 
where user= .....
```

`totaltime` and `longtime` columns are both in `userdata` table.

`TotalTime` column is inserted like that too:

```
update userdata 
set totaltime = DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE())
```

Basically I do this to convert datetime in SQL Server to unix timestamp for easier calculation, so is this all correct?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the question.

Comment: So, how I can do this?